# Angular ng-repeat unexpected number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json "names":

```
[
    {"360": "False", "2D": "True"},
    {"360": "True", "2D": "False"},
    {"360": "False", "2D": "True"},
    {"360": "True", "2D": "False"}]
```

and when i do in ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
     <td>{{name.360}}</td>
     <td>{{name.2D}}</td>
</tr>
```

in console i have "SyntaxError: Unexpected number"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need to see more of you code. How are you adding your json data to your scope?

Answer (score 4):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) since property name which starts with number(*i.e, it's not a [valid identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier)*) can't access using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation).

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name['360']}}</td>
   <td>{{name['2D']}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Rayon : just added it bro :)